# Can't install MySQL Server 5.6

Tags: mysql

When I try to install MySQL server 5.6 commercial edition (64 bit, although I get the same issue with 32 bit) I get this error message every time, and no matter what I do.  I can't progress with the installation.

> Unhandled exception has occurred in your application ... (bit about
>   what continue/quit buttons do) String was not recognized as valid
>   DateTime

I haven't had to input anything, so I presume the `datetime` field is being pulled from my computer directly. I have researched the problem and it appears that it is because I am in the UK, with `datetime` being formatted `dd/mm/yyyy` and it is expecting a `datetime` of `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Using my windows 8.1 pc, I can't find a way to change the date format to american, and if I could I'm not sure if I'd have to keep it that way every time I wanted to run the database server.

Am I missing something, is there an easy way to install this?

Comment: control panel -> region & language -> change to a U.S. type format

Comment: Thanks, i (like an idiot) tried to use windows 8 settings to change it -.-. It's working so far but taking a long time on the "starting server" configuration.

Comment: It's been a while since your issue was solved. You could post an answer yourself and accept it so this does not show up in the unanswered section. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Marc B for the following answer:

"Go to control panel -> region & language, and then change the date to a U.S. type format".